# Can't marshal array of stucts from C++ to C# in Unity

Tags: c#, pointers, struct, pinvoke, marshalling

I'm trying to pass an array of `struct`s from C++ to a Unity script in C#. When I am using the code in production, the size of the array will vary greatly, so I effectively need to pass an array of unknown length.

My clever idea was to store the array on the heap and pass a reference to that array to Unity. I've found StackOverflow posts on how to do that. But then Unity complains about a reference being null.

Here's part of my C++ code:

```c++
extern "C" struct S; // Not currently used.

struct S {
  int i;
  float f;
};

extern "C" bool helloWorld(S ** a, int * i);

S * s;

bool helloWorld(S ** a, int * i) {
  s = new S[4];
  for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
    s[j].i = j;           // Fill in placeholder
    s[j].f = (float) j;   // data for now.
  }
  *a = s; // I don't know if this works.
  *i = 4; // Works.
  return true;
}
```

I tried this with `int`s instead of `struct`s and it worked.

Now, my C# code is:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential),Serializable]
public struct S {
  int i;
  float f;
};

void Start() {
  IntPtr ptrNativeData = IntPtr.Zero;
  int itemsLength = 0;

  bool success = helloWorld(ref ptrNativeData, ref itemsLength);
  if (!success) {
    return;
  }

  S[] SArray = new S[itemsLength];  // Where the final data will be stored.
  IntPtr[] SPointers = new IntPtr[itemsLength];

  Debug.Log("Length: " + itemsLength); // Works!
  Marshal.Copy(ptrNativeData, SPointers, 0, itemsLength); // Seems not to work.

  for (int i = 0; i < itemsLength; i++) {
    Debug.Log("Pointer: " + SPointers[i]); // SPointers[0] prints 0.
    Marshal.PtrToStructure(SPointers[i], SArray[i]); // Crashes here. Boom.
  }
}

[DllImport("TestUnity")]
private static extern bool helloWorld(ref IntPtr ptrResultVerts,
    ref int resultVertLength);
```

The `Marshal.PtrToStructure` instruction says that the SPointers[i] argument is null. I checked with the Debug.Log command and indeed it does seem null: it prints as 0.

But I tried something similar with an array of `int`s earlier and that worked. What I'm not sure of is: is my problem in the C++ or in the C#? Am I not passing the right information or am I processing the right information in the wrong way?

## Solution 1

This was the first solution I came up with mostly on my own. The second solution is better.

Totally thanks to Alex Skalozub, I figured it out. One level of pointer indirection gets abstracted out during marshalling. So now, my C++ code contains:

```
S ** s; // Not a pointer to Ss, but a pointer to pointers to Ss.

bool helloWorld(S *** a, int * i) { // Pass a triple pointer.
  s = new S * [4]; // Create array of pointers.
  for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
    s[j] = new S; // Actually create each object.
    s[j]->i = j;
    s[j]->f = (float) j;
  }
  *a = s;
  *i = 4;
  return true;
}
```

And my C# code contains:

```
for (int i = 0; i < itemsLength; i++) {
  Debug.Log("Pointer: " + SPointers[i]);
  SArray[i] = (S) Marshal.PtrToStructure(SPointers[i], typeof(S));
}
```

And that's it! All the data is transferred.

Now this does leave me with a memory management problem: **every single object created in the C++ code will have to be freed**. I'm aware of that, and I'm going to take care of it next.

## Solution 2

See the checked answer. Alex's answer is much better as it makes much less use of unnecessary pointers. I used more pointers because I'd just figured out how to use them in C#.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, @Deduplicator. The C++ part is really: is my pointer arithmetic correct? Am I dereferencing the right stuff? Things like that.

Comment: Your ptrNativeData is a pointer to array of structures themselves, not to array of pointers to structures. Copying it to array of pointers and accessing them is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks! That seems blatantly obvious now that you say it that way! Of course! The thing that gets me if that the marshalling process implicitly removes a level of abstraction. For example, the `int * i` int C++ becomes an `int` in C#. I'm still not used to that.

Comment: How exactly `int*` becomes `int`? `int*` may become `int[]`, `ref int` (or `out int`, which is actually quite close to `int&` in C++), `int*` (if using unsafe instructions), or `IntPtr`, but never just `int`.

Comment: Also you have a memory leak problem, because memory allocated in unmanaged code is never freed in C# after copying data. You need either to allocate memory in managed code and pass it into C++ (so it is automatically handled by marshaller), or provide a C++ function to call corresponding `delete[]` when pointer is not needed anymore.

Comment: Between C++ and C#. My function declaration in C++ includes `int * i` and in C#, I declare an `int someInt` and pass it to the C++ function as `ref someInt`. The C++ star becomes a `ref` in C#, sort of. But the object that was declared in C# is still just an `int`. It's a bit confusing until you get used to it.

Comment: @AlexSkalozub, I don't really care about the memory leak for now. Once I get this working, I'll deal with memory management. My current plan, given how the final code will work, is to always use the same array on the head over and over again and free it before I re-assign it again. Getting the data to Unity is really my focus at this point.

Comment: @AlexSkalozub I figured it out totally thanks to you. If you could type anything as an answer, I'll credit you for the solution.

Comment: Globals variables are a bad idea, and needless

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I understand, but this is really sample code just to get the marshalling system working. My actual struct is not called "S", its instances are not called "s", and they not stored as global variables. I thought that for the purposes of this question, only showing the important parts was a better idea that expecting people to read all of my code on GitHub. Finally, as was mentioned, this code seriously leaks memory, which is also something I'm addressing but that was not relevant to this question. I thank you for the information you contributed to the whole marshalling issue.

Comment: If you could allocate the array caller side then you could pin it and be much more efficient

Comment: In practice, I won't know the size of the array on the C# size. It's going to come from a vector on the C++ side. It would be a lot simpler if I knew the size of the array in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ptrNativeData` is a pointer to array of structures themselves, not to array of pointers to structures. Copying it to array of pointers and accessing them is incorrect.

I'd also suggest to use `out` instead of `ref` when declaring an interop function. This is more accurate and doesn't require marshaller to copy initial values from managed to native code (as they're initialized in native code):

```
[DllImport("TestUnity")]
private static extern bool helloWorld(out IntPtr ptrResultVerts, out int resultVertLength);

void Start() {
    IntPtr ptrNativeData;
    int itemsLength;

    bool success = helloWorld(out ptrNativeData, out itemsLength);
    if (!success) {
        return;
    }

    S[] SArray = new S[itemsLength];  // Where the final data will be stored.

    Debug.Log("Length: " + itemsLength);

    IntPtr p = ptrNativeData;
    for (int i = 0; i < itemsLength; i++) {
        Marshal.PtrToStructure(p, SArray[i]);
        p += Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(S)); // move to next structure
    }

    // todo: free ptrNativeData later
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Alex! (Also, I don't know why my question was downvoted so much. I wish people who downvoted said why. But what can you do?)

Comment: Thanks for this solution. It works fine. but i'm wondering whats the best way to free ptrNativeData in this particular case ? Because the data is allocated on the C/C++ side, my guess is that we would need an extra call to free the memory from C/C++ side right ?

Comment: @YanivDeRidder you typically should DllImport another native function for that, and pass it `ptrNativeData` value. In the simplest case it should just call corresponding `delete []` operator (if data was allocated with `new []`), or `free()` (if allocated with `malloc()` / `calloc()`), but may also have some additional cleanup logic.

Answer (score 1):

Years Later I find this answer and it helps me a little bit. Altough I have something to add, which is easier and better to use. You don't have to worry about freeing the memory in the C++ Part:

**C++**

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)

struct Joint
{
    int id = 0;
    float posX = 0.0f;
    float posY = 0.0f;
    float posZ = 0.0f;
};

#pragma pack(pop)

extern "C" void __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall GetJointArray(Joint* newJoints, int* length)
{
    Joint theNewJoints[2];
    Joint theJoint;
    theJoint.id = 20;
    theJoint.posX = 21;
    theJoint.posY = 22;
    theJoint.posZ = 23;
    theNewJoints[0] = theJoint;
    theNewJoints[1] = theJoint;
    memcpy(newJoints, &theNewJoints, 2 * sizeof (theJoint));
    *length = 2;
}
```

C#

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 0)]
internal unsafe struct Joint
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    public int id;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R4)]
    public float posX;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R4)]
    public float posY;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R4)]
    public float posZ;
}

[DllImport("TheDLL")]
static extern void GetJointArray(Joint[] jointArray, out int length);

int itemsLength = 0;
Joint[] result = new Joint[2]; // Of course you need an additional dll function call to get the size of the array before
GetJointArray( result, out itemsLength);
Debug.Log("ITEMS LENGTH:" + itemsLength);
Debug.Log("JOINT1 ID:" + result[0].id);
```

One additional thing to mention is: You need two calls with this approach...first get the size of the array from C++ DLL, allocate the array in C# and let the C++ DLL fill the array you allocated in C# with an additional call