# Using CopyMemory from dll and throwing Access Violation Error

Tags: c#, c++, dll, access-violation, unity-game-engine

I created a C++ .dll library for use in a Unity5 C# program.

However, when I run the program from Unity editor and try to call smCopy, Unity crashes and attempts to send a bug report; instead, I traced the error to be an Access Violation Error occurring from smCopy.

The .dll library allows me to connect to a server and copy data into a given parameter via this function:

```
C++:
void DLL_API smCopy(const VOID *dest, SIZE_T len)
{
    CopyMemory((PVOID)(dest), (PVOID)(mapBuffer), len);
}
```

In my Unity Script, I import the function:

```
C#:
[DllImport(DLL_NAME, EntryPoint = "smCopy")] 
private static extern void smCopyData(IntPtr dest, IntPtr len);
```

And call it eventually:

```
C#:
{
 //  create IntPtr for message
    IntPtr msg_intptr = new IntPtr();

    smCopyData(msg_intptr, (IntPtr)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(smMsg)));

    //  create actual data struct
        // smMsg is a struct referenced in both .dll & Unity script
    smMsg data_msg = new smMsg();

    //  Set POINTER data to struct
    Marshal.PtrToStructure(msg_intptr, data_msg);
}
```

I debugged and traced the error to occur from smCopyData, with the following error found in log:

```
  `VCRUNTIME140D.dll caused an Access Violation (0xc0000005) in module VCRUNTIME140D.dll at 0033:b4761c89.`
```

The .dll works with other functions and I'm able to connect to the server successfully, apart from this occurring error.

---

Now I'm at a loss of what I could do next, as I need this function to copy the data from the server into a struct.

How would I be able to copy the memory from the server (mapBuffer) into a parameter variable from C#?

---

[Reference to Marshal & IntPtr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27390856/cant-marshal-array-of-stucts-from-c-to-c-sharp-in-unity)

Editor.log Stack Trace

```
0x00007FFBB70A1C89 (VCRUNTIME140D) memcpy
0x00007FFBB72819D9 (SharedMemoryClientDLL) [l:\projects\google\chapstick\software\working\abner\misc proj\vs\sharedmemoryclientdll\sharedmemoryclientdll\smclibrary.cpp:151] smCopy 
0x0000000012B65B29 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) SMCScript:smCopyData (intptr,intptr)
0x0000000012B65793 (Mono JIT Code) [L:\Projects\Google\chapstick\Software\Working\Abner\Misc Proj\Unity\ChapstickProject\Assets\Scripts\SMCScript.cs:202] SMCScript:GetData () 
0x0000000012B62CA3 (Mono JIT Code) [L:\Projects\Google\chapstick\Software\Working\Abner\Misc Proj\Unity\ChapstickProject\Assets\Scripts\SMCScript.cs:176] SMCScript:CheckForEvent () 
0x0000000010B69232 (Mono JIT Code) [L:\Projects\Google\chapstick\Software\Working\Abner\Misc Proj\Unity\ChapstickProject\Assets\Scripts\SMCScript.cs:150] SMCScript:Update () 
0x00000000007D68E2 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper runtime-invoke) object:runtime_invoke_void__this__ (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
0x00007FFB9B5F41BF (mono) [c:\buildslave\mono-runtime-and-classlibs\build\mono\mini\mini.c:4937] mono_jit_runtime_invoke 
0x00007FFB9B548435 (mono) [c:\buildslave\mono-runtime-and-classlibs\build\mono\metadata\object.c:2623] mono_runtime_invoke 
0x000000014033E20F (Unity) scripting_method_invoke
```

Comment: Well, looking at the C++ code, that isn't the problem.  So it has to be how you're marshaling / interfacing to the function from C#

Comment: Don't you need to create a buffer first before passing it to the C++ DLL?  I am sure that creating an IntPtr() isn't going to do this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this *is* the problem, and that you failed to allocate memory for the buffer that you're going to be copying data to.  How to do that in C# -- you need to do the research.  Just creating an IntPtr() does nothing.

Comment: Yes, I see now! Thank you very much for the feedback, I had a bad grasp on IntPtr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to allocate a buffer and pass its pointer to  the function. You are just passing an empty pointer so the cpp function is trying to write to address 0 which causes an access violation exception.

```
var len = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(smMsg));
IntPtr msg_intptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(len);
try {
    // call the function, convert output to struct, etc...
}
finally {
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(msg_intptr);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I had misunderstood the exact use and implementation of IntPtr, but I see now.